# Am I using a correct method to derive these orders?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

As an exercise I am calculating some orders of some elements but I don't know if my method is correct.

> Please can you tell me if my solutions (not the results but the steps
>   to deduce the results) are correct?

The first exercise is this:

If $|a^5| = 12$, what are the possibilities for $|a|$? If $|a^4| = 12$, what are the possibilities for $|a|$?

My method:

In general, if $|a|=n$ then $|a^k|={n\over \gcd(n,k)}$. Using this we can derive:

$$ 12 = {n\over \gcd(n,5)} \tag{$\ast$}$$

We also know that $a^{12 \cdot 5} = a^{60} = e$ and therefore $n \mid 60$. Divisors of $60$ are $1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30 $ and $60$.

From $(\ast)$ we know that $n$ is a multiple of $12$. This narrows down the possibilities for $n$ to:

$$ n \in \{12, 60\}$$

If $n=60$ then $|a^5| = 12$. Also, if $n=12$ then $|a^5|=|a|=12$. Therefore the possibilities for $n$ are $12$ and $60$.

Now for the equation $|a^4|=12$:

By the same argument as before we deduce

$$ 12 = {n\over \gcd(4,n)}$$

and $a^{4 \cdot 12} = a^{48}=e$ and therefore $n\mid 48$. Divisors of $48$ are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24$ and $48$. Again we know from the equation above that $n$ is a multiple of $12$. This narrwos down the possibilities to $$ n \in \{12,24,48\}$$

If $n=12$ then $|a^4|=3$ so this is not possible. Similarly, if $n=24$ then $|a^4|=6$. Therefore the only possible $n$ is $48$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @kaiten Thank you for your help!